# Bootstrap How to refresh the page when drop-down menu is closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I refresh the page when user close the drop down menu on click outside of it.

UPDATE

```
 <li class="dropdown" id="u_pic_link">
                        <script>
                            $('#u_pic_link').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                  })
                        </script>
```

Comment: there is no select it has only `<a>` and `<ul>`

Comment: @SahanPerara OP is talking about a Bootstrap dropdown. Not a `<select>` element

Comment: I found the mistake, script should be nested with `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`hide.bs.dropdown`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events) or [`hidden.bs.dropdown`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events) events...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="dropdown user-dropdown" id="u_pic_link">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>...</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$('#u_pic_link').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  window.location.reload();
})
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/B9z7HaDOAU)

---

If for whatever reason you need to place your javascript before the element you must use jQuery's document.ready event...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#u_pic_link').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        window.location.reload();
    })
})
```

Comment: I updated question as ur answer but still not working

Comment: The code I posted works. See the demo. There must be a problem with your implementation. Can you recreate your code on [Bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Comment: It contains server side scripting that is why I cant run my code there, by the way drop down is working fine

Comment: Use the HTML that your server-side code outputs to set up the demo. The above JS needs to be placed in your document _after_ the dropdown element or wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { ...your code... });`

Comment: Great its working now add `$(document).ready(function() {` to your answer

Comment: You should be placing your javascript at the end of your document so for most people reading this question doc.ready won't be necessary

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for an event which gets fired when the dropdown is hidden.

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
 // do something…
  window.location.reload();
 });
```

Official bootstrap documentation
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Hope this helps

Comment: @SahanPerera is the dropdown working fine? and where are you including your script tag?